# Windows 8 mobile equivalent of Xcode UIView

Tags: c#, xcode, windows-phone-8, uiview

Currently moving from Objective-C and Xcode, to C# and Visual Studio 2012.  Just wondering if there is an equivalent of the UIView in the Windows 8 Mobile world?

If so does anyone know how you create a new instance programmatically?

Cheers, Charlie

Update: Looking for an equivalent of a UIView within the main overall UIView (e.g. a small rectangle at the top of an ios app page).

Comment: Are you trying to render 3d graphics into your UIView equivalent? You will want to look at DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think

- UIView  equivalent is [PhoneApplicationPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- UIWindow equivalent , [PhoneApplicationFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this answer chamamo.  I was actually thinking of the user of UIView as small sub-views within an overall UIView (e.g. a small rectangle UIView within the overall UIView page).  Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use User control or Custom control.

briefly you can use User control if you want to separate somme fonctionality of your Main View to some pieces with reusability.

If you want to reuse your Control in different projets (ex: Custom Button Custom TextBox ...etc.) then use Custom control.